# Get "org.koin.error.BeanOverrideException" error on reopen the app

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I'm using Koin on a [modular application](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/modularizing-android-applications-9e2d18f244a0) by following [documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/getting-started/android/) of that.
I call `startKoin` on my `BaseApplication` on the Core-Module:

#### Application

```
val myModule = module {
    factory { MyClass(androidContext()) }
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoin(this, listOf(myModule))
}
```

And load some other modules in other modules by `loadKoinModules`:

```
loadKoinModules(otherModules)
```

All things are ok on first run, but when I reopen the application, I'm getting this error:

```
com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 8252
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: org.koin.error.BeanOverrideException: Try to override definition with Factory [name='MyClass',class='com.example.module.MyClass'], but override is not allowed. Use 'override' option in your definition or module.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Is there any way to destroy Koin or any other way to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val myModule = module(override = true) {
    factory { MyClass(androidContext()) }
}
```

Comment: this is now deprecated, any other way of solving this